# sending emails from websphere 7

Tags: websphere, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email from my applciation deployed in Websphere 7 in windows machine.
I am using google credentials with SSL. I have provided port 465. but email does not work and i see the following error in the logs.

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect

Why is it trying to connect port 25 where as I have given port 465.
Is there any settings in Websphere for the port?
I have done SSL handshaking and it works in Websphere7.
The same application works fine in Websphere 8.5  in Linux machine.

Comment: Can you show how & where you configured the mail server? Are you using a MailSession resource configured in WebSphere, or direct code in your application?

Comment: I am using direct code. I am not using Mailsession resource of Websphere.
All I am using is the SSL configuration in Security.I am using JAVA mail API in my application  to send emails.

Comment: Please show the code and/or configuration files.

Comment: code is a normal downloaded JAVA mail API which will accept credentials from my application. I have provided the foloowing settings in Websphere7.SSL certificate and key management > Key stores and certificates > NodeDefaultTrustStore > Signer certificates > Retrieve from port-  inputs are smtp.gmail.com port 465.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you don't show the actual code and configuration settings here, it's going to be impossible to help you troubleshoot why it's attempting to hit port 25 instead of 465